# Tkinter Avoid Decimal Dot Repeatse

Tags: python, tkinter, decimal

So I have a very simple question as I am very new to programming. Pretty much, I'm building a calculator using tkinter and I have a decimal button and a decimal bind function to bind it with the dot (.). My small problem is that my Entry Widget allows the decimal to repeat when click on the decimal button a couple of times. For instance this could happen: 873...40..4. How can I make it so my entry widget recognizes that there are multiple decimal points in an integer and so it not allows that to happen.

Here's something I've tried so far:

```
def key_decimal(number):

    string = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, string + '.')
    if string == int(string) + '..':
        e.delete(e.index('end') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.get()` returns a string, invoke `count()` method on it

```
def key_decimal(number):

    string = e.get()
    if string.count('.')<=1:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

You can substitute whatever code you need instead of True or False

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tkinter Entry validation to prevent more than 1 decimal point from being entered.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def decimal_check(proposed):
    if proposed.count('.') <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

number = Entry(window, validate="all")
number['validatecommand'] = (number.register(decimal_check),'%P')
number.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

This code will run the `decimal_check` function everytime a change is made to the entry widget. If the user tries to enter more than 1 decimal point, the value won't be updated.